# Error : Creating variables on a non-first call to a function decorated with tf.function en Keras creando RNN Simple

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Estoy creando una red neuronal recurrente que recibe un número decimal y devuelva su conversión en binario
Tengo un dataset de entrenamiento con 60000 números enteros con sus respectivos equivalente binarios, ambos números son separados en sus digitos para llenar los datasets correspondientes, así:

```
def crear_dataset(n, bits):
    train_X = np.zeros((n, bits))
    train_Y = np.zeros((n, bits))

    randNum = np.random.randint(low=0,high=2**bits, size=(n), dtype='int32')
    for i in range(len(randNum)):
        aux = [int(x) for x in str(randNum[i])]
        dec_a_bin = np.base_repr(randNum[i])
        #print(aux,dec_a_bin)
        for val in range(len(dec_a_bin)):
            train_Y[i][bits-val-1] = int(dec_a_bin[len(dec_a_bin)-val-1])

        for digit in range(len(str(randNum[i]))):
            train_X[i][bits-digit-1] = aux[len(aux)-digit-1]



    return train_X, train_Y
```

Y para llenar dicho dataset llamo a la función:

```
train_X, train_Y = crear_dataset(60000,16)
train_X = np.reshape(train_X, (train_X.shape[0], 1, train_X.shape[1]))
```

El modelo es creado de la siguiente manera:

```
n_a = 25    # Número de unidades en la capa oculta
entrada = Input(shape=(None, 16))
a0 = Input(shape=(n_a,))

celda_recurrente = SimpleRNN(n_a, activation='tanh', return_state = True)
capa_salida = Dense(16, activation='softmax')

salida = []
hs, _ = celda_recurrente(entrada, initial_state=a0)
salida.append(capa_salida(hs))
modelo = Model([entrada,a0],salida)
modelo.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
modelo.summary()
```

Activación Principal:

```
def train_generator():
    while True:
        # Activación inicial (matriz de ceros)
        a = np.zeros((len(train_X), n_a))

        yield [train_X, a], train_Y
```

Pero cuando quiero empezar el entrenamiento, obtengo el error:

```
epochs = 150

for epoch in np.arange(1, epochs):

    modelo.fit(train_generator())
```

> ValueError: Creating variables on a non-first call to a function decorated with tf.function.

Answer (score 0):

Recién probé su código, y tras añadir los `import` necesarios todo funcionó bien (no dio error, no sé el resultado si es el esperado por usted).
Vaya a [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com) y pruebe, claro, añada los siguientes `import`

```
import numpy as np
from keras import Input, Model
from keras.layers import SimpleRNN, Dense
```